# Whenever i insert a obj file, it's placed somewhere and idk how to get it normal

Tags: objects

Whenever i import a .obj file into blender, it gets placed as a orange dot. When i press numpad period, i see the object but i can't find the grid anymore?
I tried to move the camera to the orange dot but it didn't visible. I also tried to scale the object, nothing happend...

I would like to get the object on the middle of the screen. (where the cube is at the beginning)

Thank you for your reply!

regards,
Jonas

Comment: with it selected press `Alt` + `G`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, OBJs are imported relative to their own coordinate systems. So try to set it to (0,0,0) in its own environment before exporting.

Another aproach would be to hit *Shift+S > Cursor To Center*, and after that *Shift+S > Selection To Cursor* – after that, your object is centered.